# MongoDB: Compare two fields in ArrayFilter

Tags: mongodb

Imagine I have such objects in mongo collection:

```
{
    "id": "some id",
    "arrayField": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "field1": "value A",
            "field2": "value B"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "field1": "value C",
            "field2": "value C"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to write UpdateOne query with [ArrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) to update elements of arrayField where value of *field1* equals to value of *field2*. According to the above example, after executing this query, ArrayFilter should select second element of arrayField (with "id": "2") because it's field1 equals to field2. How to write ArrayFilters part for this query?

Comment: What do you mean by `subObject`? What is you mongo version?

Comment: @Ashh My mongo version is 4.0.2. SubObjects are elements of "arrayField" array.

Answer (score 1):

An aggregation query can be used to select the `arrayField` elements (array has elements; and in this case there are two elements as sub-documents) based on a condition.

Array field of a document can be filtered using the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) aggregation operator. The query when applied to the sample document in the question returns the document only the sub-document  with `"id": "2"`.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $project: { 
          arrayField: {
              $filter: {
                   input: "$arrayField",
                      as: "ele",
                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$ele.field1", "$$ele.field2" ] }
               }
         }
      }
  }
] )

{
        "id" : "some id",
        "arrayField" : [
                {
                        "id" : "2",
                        "field1" : "value C",
                        "field2" : "value C"
                }
        ]
}
```

In case you want to *update* the document in the collection, use the following script with the result of the aggregation query:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $project: { // fill the code from the above query here...
  }
] ).forEach( doc => db.test.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { arrayField: doc.arrayField } } ) );
```